# Scroll directly where you click without keyboard by one click

Tags: windows, scrollbar

By holding `shift`, you can jump straight forward to any point you click on the scrollbar whatever the application but how to do this by default without pressing any keyboard button and by one click ?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps such as Windows Explorer for example display a context menu when you right-click the scrollbar:

[image: 1]

As far as I know there's no way to globally change scrollbar behaviour in Windows to do what you want, at least not without third party hacks.

Comment: Indeed this is not exactly the feature I want but it's always good to know. I edited my request for better accuracy.